# How to play a sound at a given MIDI note/octave?

Tags: c++, language-agnostic, midi, directsound

I'm reverse engineering a music format which seems to be MIDI with a sound bank.

However I can't get my implementation to sound correct because I don't know how to play a sample from the sound bank at a given MIDI note (I just play them at their native khz).

So my question is - if I have some sound in a wave file such as foo.wav @ 44100khz and a MIDI note of 0 to 127, then how do I play it at this note?

I'm using Win32 API and DirectSound - but I don't think this matters as I assume the theory can be applied anywhere.

Comment: Try downloads.dspdimension.com/smbPitchShift.cpp‎, though look more into Pitch Shifting, it is not a trivial problem.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: Pitch Shifting is not a trivial problem but playing the sample quicker or more slowly is and enough in many cases.

Answer (score 4):

You have to play back the sample at a different rate so that its pitch is correct.

Both the sample and the MIDI event have a note.
Use a formula from [Note names, MIDI numbers and frequencies](http://www.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/notes.html) to compute both frequencies:

```
f = 440Hz * 2^((m−69)/12)
```

then, with the actual and desired frequencies, you know the ratio by which the speed of the sample must be changed.

---

For example, if you have a 44.1 kHz sample of a note played at B4, and if you get a MIDI event that wants to play a note at D5, then the sample's note frequency is 493.88 Hz, while it should be played so that the note's frequency is at 587.33 Hz.
In other words, it should be sped up by a factor of 587.33/493.88 ≈ 1.19.

So instead of playing that sample at 44.1 kHz, it must be played at 44.1 kHz × 1.19 ≈ 52.4 kHz.

Assuming that your output device still runs at 44.1 kHz, you have to resample that note sample.
To do that, tell the resampler that you want to convert from 52.4 kHz to 44.1 kHz.

---

Note: when computing the ratio between the frequencies of two notes `m1` and `m2`, the `440 Hz` and `69` terms cancel out, and you get:

```
f1 / f2 = 2 ^ ((m1 - m2) / 12)
```

Comment: I'm confused.. so if the value of f for a given sample is the note 21/"A" and I want to play it as 21, then nothing needs to be changed? But if it was 30 then I'd down sample by 9?

Comment: Sorry, I should not have used the word "resample"; you need to treat the sample as if it had a different rate. (You still need to resample it to the rate of the output device.)

Comment: Could you add an example of say a 44100khz sample in the note of B being played at D calculated? I'm still pretty clueless :(